# Accessing Template items of UserControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

Is it possible to implement custom `UserControl` or `Control`, which will act like a `PlaceHolder`, but with my logic? Example of using:

```
<x:MyControl runat="server">
    <Template>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="MyTextBox" />
        ..... any custom code here ........
    </Template>
</x:MyControl>
```

And then in code-behind:

```
MyTextBox.Text = "ABC";
```

I implemented test control, but I am unable to access nested ASP controls on the page level. Error is `The name "MyTextBox" does not exist in the current context`.

Comment: @JohnSaunders hum that's not true.

Answer (score 1):

You must call the function "FindControl" in you user control MyControl.
Name you MyControl with and `id="mcContainer"`, then on your code behind call `((TextBox)mcContainer.FindControl("MyTextBox")).Text = "ABC";`.

Wiki about this here [How to: Create Templated ASP.NET User Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36574bf6%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Why can I write `MyTextBox.Text="ABC"` when it is in the Page and why isn't that possible when the text box is inside of naming container implemented by a user control?

Well, when you drag N dropped your text box the ASP.NET Page designer declared a variable for you in the partial class of your page reserved for the designer itself, is in that designer part of your class that your controls in you page are declared.

So when you drag and drop your user control, and create a text box inside of it's naming container you can't access it directly because your page doesn't hold a reference to that control, the reason for that is because that control will only be available at runtime during the instanciation of the user control itself, the motive is related in part with the way that ASP.NET page parser renders controls.

Quoting this [resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478964.aspx):
When working with composite controls it is important to be familiar with a number of properties and methods, as well as with the INamingContainer interface. All composite controls should implement the INamingContainer interface. Controls that implement this interface do not need to add any methods or properties; rather, the implemented interface merely indicates that the control is being used as a composite control. The effect is that child controls—that is, controls in the composite control's Controls collection—are rendered so that their ID is prefixed with the ID of the control's naming container. This ensures that all the child controls will have unique ID values, even if there are multiple instances of the parent control on a Form. The WebControl class has a NamingContainer property that returns the control's parent.

So, when you write MyTextBox, your text box name should at least something like $mcContainer$MyTextBox. So because of this there is no way to transparently do what you intend.

Comment: Well, okay, forget about `UserControl`. Is it possible to reinvent functionality of `PlaceHolder`? (Everything works even without `Template` there).

Comment: How is that? Reinvent, can you detail more?

Comment: @JohnSaunders :) .NET is a world, I've done this couple years ago, but gave some headaches though..

Comment: @JoãoPinho, I mean is it possible to create a custom `Control`, which can transparently have nested controls, and these controls are visible on page level directly, without `FindControl`, absolutely like in `Panel` or `PlaceHolder`?

Comment: @Denis: yes, it's possible to do that with a custom control - and apparently also with a user control

Comment: @JohnSaunders Jonh, he wants to write MyTextBox.Text="something", just like this, in the page, being the MyTextBox declared inside the UserControl/ServerControl. But he can't do that.

Comment: No, not with a template. You're right. I believe I've seen other complex server controls which have a rich structure, some of which gets promoted to members of the page. But you're right - most do not.

Comment: @Denis the answer is no Dennis, sorry but you can't do it like that. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Solution.

Create class like this:

```
public class ToolTip : PlaceHolder
{
    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        HtmlGenericControl div1 = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
        div1.Attributes.Add("id", ClientID);
        div1.Attributes.Add("class", "tooltip");
        while (Controls.Count != 0)
            div1.Controls.Add(Controls[0]);
        Controls.Add(div1);
    }
}
```

Then register it in ASPX file like this:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="YOUR_ASSEMBLY" TagPrefix="x" Namespace="YOUR_NAMESPACE" %>
```

Then use it like this:

```
<x:ToolTip runat="server">
    ... any your content here ......
</x:ToolTip>
```

Now you are able to nest any controls inside of `x:ToolTip` and add any composition logic to `CreateChildControls()`.